# I want to add two df columns df['Date'] and df['hour'] to create the column timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

The problem is the hour column and the date column are like this:

[image: [enter image description here]

Is there any way to add them to get a column starting with 2019-07-01 7:00:00 and so on

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta('1H') * df['Hour']

# or
# df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'], unit='H')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['datetime'] = df[['Date', 'hour']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

then:

```
df['datetime']= pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
df.apply(lambda t : pd.datetime.combine(t['date_column_name'],t['time_column_name']),1)
```

If both columns are string you can simply concatenate it as well